# Creating user profiles that are editable by users

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, content-management-system, user-experience

Several sites have the ability for users to create profiles from Facebook to StackOverflow. I have experience with the WordPress CMS, is it possible to create a user profile upon registration that a user can edit when signed in?

I feel as though this may get closed for being vague, but I have been unable to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Register plus with Users Manager Plugin which give you the Ability to control and add field on Registration and on users Dashboard...

Goodluck

Comment: I would like to avoid using plugins, I would like to know the direction of coding such a thing.